# For the integral operator $(Af)(t) = \int_0^1K(t,s)f(s)ds$ in $L_2[0,1]$, prove that $\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} |a_{nm}|^2 = ||K||^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $K$ be a continuous function in $L_2[0,1]^2$. Let $A$ be the integral operator in $L_2[0,1]$:
$$(Af)(t) = \int_0^1K(t,s)f(s)ds$$

Since $L_2[0,1]$ is a separable hilbert space, then $A$ can be represented as a matrix $A = (a_{nm})$ in an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$.

I want to show that $\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} |a_{nm}|^2 = ||K||^2$, and it is allowed to assume that $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ are continuous in order to avoid using Lebesgue integration.

However, I am having to understand how exactly I use the matrix representation with functions, so I'm not sure what to do.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_{nm}=(A(e_m),e_n)$, then

$$\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} |a_{nm}|^2=\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} |(A(e_m),e_n)|^2=\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} \left| \int_{0}^1 A(e_m)(t)\overline{e_n(t)}dt\right|^2=\sum_{n,m=1}^{\infty} \left|\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^1 K(t,s)e_m(s)\overline{e_n(t)}ds dt\right|^2$$

Now, using that $e_{nm}(t,s):=\overline{e_n(t)}e_m(s)$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2([0,1]^2)$ we should have the last expression be equal to $\|K\|^2$, by parseval's identity. Here I am understanding that $\|K\|$ is the norm that comes from $L^2([0,1]^2)$.

Comment: A clear answer, thanks!